# How is the power rule applied to whole numbers

Tags: calculus, derivatives

For the following function, how does the $+1$ become $0$ when finding its derivative via the power rule?

Original function: $f(x) = 6x^2 − 4x^{-1} + 5x^{-2} − 2x + 1$

Derivative: $f '(x) = 12x + 4x^{-2} − 10x^{-3} − 2$

Comment: It doesn't. The $-2x$ becomes $-2$.

Comment: Whoops careless mistake. I will edit the question. But I mean't to say how +1 becomes 0.

Comment: Using the power rule: $\frac{d}{dx} ax^n = nax^{n - 1}$. $1 = 1x^0$, and so $\frac{d}{dx} 1 = 0 \cdot 1 \cdot x^{-1} = 0$.

Comment: Just remember all constants can be removed when taking the derivative. You don't have to worry about them because they all become $0$.

Comment: Very true. However, I also wanted to know how it works for personal understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the power rule: $\frac{d}{dx} ax^n = nax^{n - 1}$. $1 = 1x^0$, and so $\frac{d}{dx} 1 = 0 \cdot 1 \cdot x^{-1} = 0$.

Alternately, with the definition of the derivative:

$\frac{d}{dx} f(x) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(x + h)}{h}$. In this particular case, $f(x)$ is the constant function $1$.

This gives $\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{1 - 1}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} 0 = 0$.

Comment: I could be wrong, but doesn't that give $0 \over 0$, thus undefinable? (For the limit definition)

Comment: Nope. $\frac{0}{h} = 0$ for all $h$, and is equal to taking the limit as $h \to 0$ of the constant function $0$. More formally, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ (In fact, any $\delta > 0$ works, so we'll take $\delta = 1$) such that if $h_1,h_2 \ne 0$, $|h_1 - h_2| < \delta$, then $|\frac{0}{h_1} - \frac{0}{h_2}| < \varepsilon$. Since limits don't care about the value at the point that the limit is taken to, simply ignoring the case where $h = 0$ is fine.

Comment: So you're saying, similarly, if 1 was another number (let's say 3) then d/dx3=0⋅3⋅x^−1=0?

Comment: Yes. Both arguments given hold for any constant function, be it $1,3,\pi,0,\frac{7}{4},\dots$ (Though the power rule, used in the first argument, depends on an argument of the second sort to be shown to be true.)